# Why is Excel Macro recognizing − as a question mark?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to convert a column which has both positive and negative percentages into plain numbers. For example, -3.5% to 3.5. There is no problem converting positive percentage to simple numbers. For negative numbers though, result is showing as FALSE.

I suspect the problem is with this character at the beginning −0.27% and its different from the usual minus (-0.27%). How to write a macro to solve this problem?

Macro code:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IF(EXACT(LEFT(RC[-4],1),""""),RIGHT(RC[-4],LEN(RC[-4])-1)*-1*100,IF(EXACT(LEFT(RC[-4],1),0),RC[-4]*100))"
```

Comment: To answer the question in your title, the VBA Editor only recognizes codes in the range of '[00-FF]` .  Codes higher than `FF` are rendered as the question mark (`3F`).  Your data is including the unicode minus sign (`2212`) so is being rendered as a `?`.  To correct the problem, merely replace the Unicode minus sign with the ASCII hyphen-minus, as mentioned by @Siddharth Rout

Answer (score 1):

Replace `−` with `-` and then convert it.

Try

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=ABS(SUBSTITUTE(RC[-4],""−"",""-""))"
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Sub Macro1()
   ActiveCell.Value = "=ABS(RC[-4])*100"
   ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "General"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need macro for this you can simply use the Excel's built in function **ABS**

Like below

=ABS(A2)*100

If you need to automate using VBA then also you can use the **ABS** function.